# Overflow content hidden inside fixed width container with overflow as scroll

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm fairly new to flexbox. I have a container div with fixed width and overflow-x as scroll.
However the overflowing content of children towards left direction is hidden and only scrolling for right direction overflow content. As seen in the fiddle, node 1 of row 2 is hidden and not visible even on scrolling towards left.

I tried giving width as 100% to child element. This is a jsfiddle replicating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/e473t20d/

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row center-h">
    <div class="node">1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row center-h">
    <div class="node">1</div>
    <div class="node">2</div>
    <div class="node">3</div>
    <div class="node">4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="node">1</div>
    <div class="node">2</div>
    <div class="node">3</div>
    <div class="node">4</div>
    <div class="node">5</div>
    <div class="node">6</div>
    <div class="node">7</div>
    <div class="node">8</div>
    <div class="node">9</div>
    <div class="node">10</div>
    <div class="node">11</div>
    <div class="node">12</div>
    <div class="node">13</div>
    <div class="node">14</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

````css
.row{
  display: flex;
}

.row.center-h{
  justify-content: center;
}

/* .column{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
} */

.container{
  max-width: 16em;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-left: 10em;
}

.node{
  padding: 1em 2em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #efefef;
  margin: 1em;
}

```[screenshot][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJnAb.png
````

Comment: just remove the max-width from .container

Comment: The problem is `justify-content: center`. See the duplicate for an explanation.